# Compare each element of one array to another and find which element is not found

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array which contains special characters am trying to compare each element of one array to another and get the element which is not found in another array. But my approach doesnt work properly

var specialChar = ['!','@','#','$','%','&'];
   var  $scope.inp= ['!','*','#'];

In my above example element '*' is not present specialChar

I tried this logic -

```
    $scope.validateChar = function(specialChar,inp){
  var i,j;
     for (i=0,j=0; i<specialChar.length && j<inp.length;) {
         if (specialChar[i] < inp[j]) {
             ++i;
         } else if (specialChar[i] == inp[j]) {
             ++i; ++j;
         } else {
             $scope.notFoundChar = inp[j];
```

Error prompt showing special charatcter $scope.notFoundChar not found

```
             $scope.charAllowedText = false;
             return;
         }
        }

       }
```

Please suggest what am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out your Special char '*' like below

```
var result=[]
inp.map(function(inpElement){
  if(specialChar.indexOf(inpElement)==-1)
   result.push(inpElement)
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This does not help the OP to know what was wrong with their code.

Answer (score 1):

Below given code solves your problem.

```js
var source = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var target =[2,3,4,5,6,18,19];
var missingItems = [];
target.forEach(function(itemFromTarget){
 var itemFound = false;
 source.forEach(function(itemFromSrc){
  if(itemFromTarget === itemFromSrc){
   itemFound = true;
  }
 });
 if (!itemFound) {
  missingItems.push(itemFromTarget);
 }
});
console.log(missingItems);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response